# is there a way to make navigator follow screen after title?

Tags: html, css

so I want to make a simple thing and I meet a problem:

I want my Navigator can follow where we scrolled to but don't move when we haven't scrolled after title text.
In another way to explain it, the Navigator will follow where we're at after we scrolled over title and the navigator will stay at below the title text and at left side before following.

here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>a title</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<style>
  body {
    background: rgb(20, 20, 20);
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  .titlecontainer,
  .contentcontainer {
    background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  
  .titletext {
    color: rgb(102, 212, 255);
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  .text {
    color: rgb(102, 212, 255);
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: left;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  
  .nav::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: hidden;
  }
  
  .navigator {
    color: rgb(102, 212, 255);
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  .content {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .contentcontainer {
    margin-left: 250px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="titlecontainer">
    <p class="titletext">Title</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">

    <nav>
      <p class="navigator">Navigator</p>
      <br>
      <p class="navigator">Top</p>
      <p class="navigator">Chapters</p>
      <p class="navigator">- Chapter 1</p>
      <p class="navigator">- Chapter 2</p>
      <p class="navigator">Bottom</p>
    </nav>

    <div class="contentcontainer">
      <p class="text">contents</p>
      <br>
      <p class="text">contents</p>
      <br>
      <p class="text">contents</p>
      <br>
      <p class="text">contents</p>
      <br>
      <p class="text">contents</p>
      <br>
      <p class="text">contents</p>
      <br>
      <p class="text">contents</p>
      <br>
      <p class="text">contents</p>
      <br>
      <p class="text">contents</p>
      <br>
      <p class="text">contents</p>
      <br>
      <p class="text">contents</p>
      <br>
      <p class="text">contents</p>
      <br>
      <p class="text">contents</p>
      <br>
      <p class="text">contents</p>
      <br>
      <p class="text">contents</p>
      <br>
      <p class="text">contents</p>
      <br>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

here's 2 pictures for explaining what I want to make:

1. [before scrolling (at top)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pug50.png)
2. [after scrolling down (cant see the title)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfHNe.png)

Comment: So you want the title to be fixed at its position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) instead of `position: fixed` on `nav`

```
nav {
      position: sticky; /* Change this from `fixed` to `sticky` */
      top: 1rem; /* Create the top gap */
      left: 0;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: left;
      overflow-y: hidden;

      border-radius: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>

  <style>
    body {
      background: rgb(20, 20, 20);
      margin: 0px;
    }

    .titlecontainer,
    .contentcontainer {
      background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
      border-radius: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
    }

    .titletext {
      color: rgb(102, 212, 255);
      font-size: 35px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0px;
    }

    .text {
      color: rgb(102, 212, 255);
      font-size: 20px;
      margin: 0px;
    }

    nav {
      position: sticky;
      top: 1rem;
      left: 0;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: left;
      overflow-y: hidden;

      border-radius: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
    }

    .nav::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: hidden;
    }

    .navigator {
      color: rgb(102, 212, 255);
      font-size: 20px;
      margin: 0px;

    }

    .content {
      display: flex;
    }

  </style>

  <body>
    <div class="titlecontainer">
      <p class="titletext">Title</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">

      <nav>
        <p class="navigator">Navigator</p>
        <br>
        <p class="navigator">Top</p>
        <p class="navigator">Chapters</p>
        <p class="navigator">- Chapter 1</p>
        <p class="navigator">- Chapter 2</p>
        <p class="navigator">Bottom</p>
      </nav>

      <div class="contentcontainer">
        <p class="text">contents</p>
        <br>
        <p class="text">contents</p>
        <br>
        <p class="text">contents</p>
        <br>
        <p class="text">contents</p>
        <br>
        <p class="text">contents</p>
        <br>
        <p class="text">contents</p>
        <br>
        <p class="text">contents</p>
        <br>
        <p class="text">contents</p>
        <br>
        <p class="text">contents</p>
        <br>
        <p class="text">contents</p>
        <br>
        <p class="text">contents</p>
        <br>
        <p class="text">contents</p>
        <br>
        <p class="text">contents</p>
        <br>
        <p class="text">contents</p>
        <br>
        <p class="text">contents</p>
        <br>
        <p class="text">contents</p>
        <br>
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Well is it working ?

Comment: s/he is struggling to stick the navigator on the left side. This is a possible solution for the above problem @Ashishsah